# Referencing a SASS file from HAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

How do I reference a .sass file from a .haml file?

I have the following haml expression that will reference a .css file:

```
%link{'href' => '/stylesheets/layout.css?cache=1', 'rel' => 'stylesheet', 'type' => 'text/css'}/
```

How do I reference a .sass file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sass files compile to CSS files. If you're using Rails, this is done automatically; otherwise, you can use the `sass` command-line executable. Check out [the Sass documentation](http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/SASS_REFERENCE.md.html#using_sass) for more information.

Once you've compiled your Sass files to CSS, you reference the CSS file just like you normally do.

Comment: I am having to use the command line executable.  Rails is not automatically compiling it.  Is there anything I have to do to tell rails it has sass files?

Comment: Make sure you've got the plugin installed or you're loading it from the gem by adding `config.gem "haml"` to your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

try using the [stylesheet_link_tag](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/stylesheet_link_tag) method

```
stylesheet_link_tag "layout"
```